# Always re-create database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

how can I re-create database every time when I run application or if any changes has been changed?

Should I use some method in dbcontext or in Startup.cs class?

I'm using asp.net core

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to "Always re-create the database during development", but it would be nice to have it clear that this is for a development or staging environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this while testing/developing:

```
dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```